# Mysql Invalid syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get some value from mysql

```
          $email = $_SESSION['email'];
          $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email); 
          $depst = "SELECT dept FROM  stud_reg WHERE email='$email'";
          $query="SELECT * FROM  events WHERE `group`='$depst'";
```

But i am getting an unknown error.

```
      You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '**@**.com''' at line 1
```

Although i coudn't find any syntax errors

Comment: Other than the fact that you completely forgot to run the first query?

Comment: I didnt get that @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think it's intended as a subquery.

Comment: Try to remove the ` from group.

Comment: You need to enclose the subquery in `()` as `SELECT * FROM events where \`group\` = (SELECT dept FROM....)`

Comment: @IagoMelanias group is a reserved mysql word, so i need to add backticks there

Comment: Standard disclaimer about the `mysql_*()` functions applies:  The `mysql_*()` extension was deprecated last year and will eventually be removed from PHP. Now is the time to begin learning to use a modern API supporting prepared statements, like PDO.  New code should not be written with mysql_query()

Comment: Here's an idea: for debugging, `echo` out the SQL text before you submit it to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't execute the 1st query, just use it as a subquery in the last statement :

Change

```
$query="SELECT * FROM  events WHERE `group`='$depst'";
```

for

```
$query="SELECT * FROM  events WHERE `group`=($depst)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (please [read this](http://bobby-tables.com) for more information). You should use prepared statements for this kind of thing:

```
$mysqli->prepare("SELECT dept FROM  stud_reg WHERE email=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

References:

- [PHP: `mysqli::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [Bobby tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection (PHP)](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html)

Comment: The fact is that we don't know since we don't know the source of `$_SESSION['email']`. There is no hint that let us think that the source is from a `$_POST` or a `$_GET`. So if `$_SESSION['email']` is retrieve from a db as example, there is no problem there

Comment: @FabienTheSolution agreed, but I've learned a painful lesson: when things can go wrong, they *will* go wrong... so it's a good discipline to use prepared statements every time, just to make sure bad things won't happen